# 12.04 cant play sounds

Tags: 12.04, sound

Hi I have a problem with my sound with Ubuntu it just stopped play sounds out of no where today and i don't know why. It can play sounds out of the headphone jack still. I'm running Ubuntu on a Dell Latitude D620 please help. thanks!

Comment: Maybe a hardware issue? Does the laptop have a switch to mute the speakers or something?

Comment: no there isn't a button or a switch only one for the wifi

Comment: Something similar happened to me. Go to "System Settings" > "Sound" select analog output instead of digital. "Test Sound" and let us know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Run the terminal command `alsamixer`.

Adjust the settings with cursor keys/ arrows.

This should work.